# Where to place javascript tag with function in PL/SQL

Tags: javascript, html, plsql

I'm trying to have an error checking where if the user does not input anything in the txt box then an alert will pop up prompting to put something in. The function is not working currently when I test it in the front end of thje webpage. Here is my code, I am running this code in TOAD for Oracle.

```
   <p width = 100% align="left">

  <form name ="myForm" action="alfred_first_package.Submit_Button" method="post" >    

  <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" summary="">   

     <tr>
        Create New User
     </tr>

     <tr><td>* Employee ID:</td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="EID" id="EID" onblur="checkTextField(this);" /></td></tr>

     <tr><td>* Employee Name:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Ename" id ="Ename"  onblur="checkTextField(this);" /></td></tr>


     </table>

     <br> <input type ="submit" name="SubmitInfo" value="Submit Information"/>

     </form>

    </table>



    <script>
    function checkTextField(field) {
    if (field.value == '') {
    alert("Field is empty");
  }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: "Not working" is quite broad, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not appear complete. The function will run as soon as the page loads, so it will not do what you want even if it was referring to a text field. You need to listen for when the user clicks submit, and then check the value of an input on the page. See example.

```html
<input id="txtName" type="text">
<input id="btnCheckInput" type="button" value="Check my name input">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var txtName = document.getElementById('txtName');
  var btnCheckInput = document.getElementById('btnCheckInput');
  
  btnCheckInput.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (txtName.value===''){
      alert('Name input is empty');
    }
  });
</script>
```